# Tracking high useage sites in Apache on CentOS

Tags: apache-2.2

My CPU average usage is about 0.25 - 0.3.

Is there any way to find out from apache which sites/domains are taking up most of those resources?

I'm on CentOS

Comment: Would this be better on SF?

Comment: Don't want to nitpick, but CentOS is Linux, not Unix

Answer (score 1):

But yes, it should be doable... apachetop might be a good place to start.  Then you could try something like awstats.  Or, you could maybe use suexec to have different sites run as different users, then compare the processes for each user in top.

If anyone knows a more direct way, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable apache2  mod_info ( http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_info.html ), and monitor the most cpu-intensive requests.